# Why css backdrop-filter: blur() is working well except on active bootstrap-4 list-group-item?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, sass

I have gallery, inside gallery there is album-card component, and inside there is carousel.
When i added list-group and set one of items active it remains not blurred, and I don't understand why. Can anyone explain it to me?

this is gallery component html:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a 
                    *ngFor="let album of galleryAlbums" 
                    class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary list-group-item-action 
                           d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
                    routerLink="/gallery"
                    [queryParams]="{ selectedAlbumId: album.id }"
                    [class.active]="selectedAlbumId === album.id">
                    
                    {{ album.name }}
                    <span class="badge badge-warning badge-pill">{{ album.photos.length}}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <album-card class="col-9" *ngIf="selectedAlbum" [album]="selectedAlbum"></album-card>
    </div>
```

carousel styles in .scss file:

```css
.gallery-carousel {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Can you share runable code using Codesandbox or any other online IDE

Comment: With the limited info provided I can safely assume that this has something to do with bootstrap4 having its own css properties for .active element selectors which are overriding your style properties. The first thing you can do is try to add ‘!important’ to your properties and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was in an CSS property added by Bootstrap for the `.active` class:

```css
.list-group-item.active {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

So when I added z-index f.e. 5 to my `.gallery-carousel` it covered the problematic active list group item